# Get column values of a DataFrame if values of same column name matches and the name of the column matches row value of another DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have two following dataframes `df1` and `df2`:

`df1`:

| ID | number | Result |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 13256 | 99 | NaN |
| 15556 | 100 | NaN |
| 14556 | 100 | NaN |

`df2`:

| 13256 | 15556 | 14556 | number |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 12 | 1 | 4 | 99 |
| 10 | 2 | 5 | 100 |
| 11 | 3 | 6 | 101 |

Basically, I want to get the values from `df2` where values in the `number` columns match and the name of the column in `df2` matches the row value of `ID` column in `df1`. The values I get, I want to add them in column `Result` in `df1`.

So the **expected output** is:

| ID | number | Result |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 13256 | 99 | 12 |
| 15556 | 100 | 2 |
| 14556 | 100 | 5 |

I tried something like this but still couldn't succeed it:

```py
    for index, row in df1.iterrows():
        if ((row['ID'] in df2.columns) and (df2.loc[0, 'number'] == row['number'])):
    
            value = row['number']
            print(value)
```

I appreciate any help!

Comment: Please paste all data as text and not images

Comment: @cs95 you can't imagine how many times I've closed to this, it should be a must read before your can post a pandas question (good job!) :p

Comment: @cs95 I don't like him. Pirates aren't my thing. They steal my stuff.

Comment: @mozway oh I believe you alright, 1000+ dupes and counting ... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/linked/53645882?sort=newest

Comment: @Andreasdetestscensorship I see you detest more than just censorship :-D

Comment: I edited my post, sorry for the previous one.

Comment: I checked the link that was shared but couldn't find a proper solution for my case. Could you help me with that?

Comment: @complog could you add the expected output to the post as well please

Comment: it looks like you need to melt `df2` first, then merge on both ID and number.